# Getting multipolygon vertexes to points in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I want to extract the coordinates of the vertices of a polygon, and then create a point on each of the vertices.

Sample of Polygon geometry table (multipolygon):
[image: polygon feature representation of airport worldwide runways]

Wished output:
[image: point feature representation of the polygon vertex]

Answer (score 2):

After several searches on the internet with possible solutions to this question, I found this [code](https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2015/11/06/getting-multipolygon-vertexes-using-postgis/) and I adapted to my data.
Obtaining the vertices of a polygon, extracting its coordinates, assigning an identifier in clockwise order, generating points on the vertices and eliminate the "5" point that is equal to the first(vertex where the polygon closes):

```
--transform coordinate system
with newgeom as (
    select
        gid, --geographic identifier
        st_transform(geom, 4326) as geom
        from aviation.runways
    ),
    --extracting the coordinates of the vertices of the polygon into points
    coord as (
    SELECT
        gid,
        ST_dumppoints(geom) as dump
        FROM newgeom as foo
        GROUP BY gid, geom),
    g as (
        select
        gid as gid_original,
        (coord.dump).path[1] AS part, --get out ring polygon
        (coord.dump).path[3] as vertex, --get point (vertex)
        (coord.dump).geom as geom
        from coord
    )
    select
        --creating new gid for the subsequent elimination of the redundant "5" vertex
        row_number() over () as gid,
        gid_original,
        vertex,
        st_x(g.geom) as long, --set x coord of the vertex
        st_y(g.geom) as lat, --set y coord of the vertex
        g.geom::geometry('POINT', 4326) as geom, --re-assigning geometry
        st_astext(geom)as type_geometry
    from g
    where (g.gid_original, g.part, g.vertex) NOT IN
    (select
        g.gid_original,
        g.part,
        max(g.vertex) as max --showing just the vertex not include in the maximum list vertex (i.e last one)
        from g
        group by g.gid_original, g.part);
```

Does anyone know a more efficient way, a simpler code to achieve this?